# Render collection [where(store: current_user).each do] ? how to load specific data from render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry, this may seem simple.

I'm using '*render @orders*' but I need only the orders where that have the *Storeid = current_user*

I'd normally do

```
Order.where(Storeid: current_user).each do |order|
```

ect ect

But I'm unsure how to do this with *render*.

Comment: `@orders = Order.where(store_id: current_user.id) ; render json: @orders` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the `@orders` instance variable in your controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @orders = Order.where(store_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Then in your view `app/views/orders/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= render @orders %>
```